# Simply converting from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction for changing my script into mysqli? I built the script below fully with mysql and it works **perfectly** but I have since been told that mysql_ is depreciated and I now need to use mysqli. (before mysql_ dies out and I'm left with an error fuelled website).

script:

```
<?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$name= (isset($_POST['image_author']));
$description= ($_POST['image_description']);
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);


// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("image_gallery") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (image_author, image_description, image_pathname)
VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$pic'");

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory <p> <a href='upload.php'> Go back</a>";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: See over there on the right where it says "Related"? There are about half a dozen questions about the same thing. Have you read them?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Start by reading this page about how to avoid SQL injection in PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: It's _deprecated_, not _depreciated_.

Comment: @TheBlueDog typing error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I used it as below. Here change db_name = your original database ame

db.php (create a separate connection file)

```
$db_hostname = "localhost";  //usually "localhost be default"
$db_username = "root";  //your user name
$db_pass = "root";  //the password for your user
$db_name = "yourdatabasename";  //the name of the database

// connect to database
$db = new mysqli ($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($db->connect_error) {
trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $db->connect_error,   E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Now this is your file

```
<?php
include('db.php');
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$name= (isset($_POST['image_author']));
$description= ($_POST['image_description']);
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);


// Connects to your Database
mysqli_select_db($db,"image_gallery") or die(mysqli_error($db)); 

//Writes the information to the database
$result = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO images (image_author, image_description, image_pathname) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$pic')");

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory <p> <a href='upload.php'> Go back</a>";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry @koc but there are errors here that won't work - `mysqli_error()`

Comment: you want to make a separate connection file see at above my 1st code, which name is db.php, and $db comes out from this connection file.

Comment: sorry my bad, I overlooked db.php

Comment: You must change 4th line of db.php with your database name. Go ahead.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I uploaded and everything is working perfect, the only issue is the warning that appears "Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given", which I'm not fully understanding as it states about one database, should there be another connect function within the db.php?

Comment: you need to tell MySQL which database connection to use: 'mysqli_select_db($db,"image_gallery") or die(mysqli_error($db)) ;'

Comment: I have a few mistake. Please paste this line:  $result = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO images (image_author, image_description, image_pathname) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$pic')");

Comment: I mean replace with previous line with current edited line.

Comment: Martin you are right. I overlooked it also. Thank you.

Comment: It works! My only issue now is that the 'author' comes up as a number and not the text typed in but I'm sure that's for another day - phew!      Thank you both so much, you have no idea how much I was stressing over this. Thank you both, again.

Comment: I've just literally fixed the author issue, all complete. Thank you!!! :D

Comment: Thank you too. If this solution works you can tick the tick beside my answer at the top, or the topic. and/or click the up arrow to add credit to my answer. .

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.

1- First, fix your code to work *properly* with `mysql_*` functions. You are *wide open* to SQL injections right now. Then upgrade.

2- (preferred) Scrap the code, because it is wrong and vulnerable. Start over with something better, like [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared queries, and never worry about injection again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree entirely with Niet the Dark Absol, regarding a preferred method such as Object Orientated MySQLi (or PDO)

But, I was in a similar position to you not so long ago- and here's the quick and dirty solution:

1) Build a MySQLi connection to the database, replace (comment out) your current connection.

example:

```
$dbuser="XXX";
$db="YYY";
$dbpass="TTTTT";
$MysqliLink = mysqli_connect("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
if ( ! $MysqliLink )
    {
    die("Connection Error (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") ". mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_close($MysqliLink);
    }
mysqli_set_charset($MysqliLink, "utf8");
```

The only bit that might be new to you is to use a variable that is COMPLETELY UNIQUE to your website, and unlikely to be accidentally overwritten, for `$MysqliLink` . Once this is done and set you can move onto stage 2:

2)
Search and replace your entire site with the following:

`mysql_query("` --> becomes --> `mysqli_query($MysqliLink, "`

`mysql_error()` --> becomes --> `mysqli_error($MysqliLink)`

`mysql_` --> becomes --> `mysqli_`

There are a couple of functions that change, such as:
 `mysql_num_rows()` --> becomes --> `mysqli_num_rows($MysqliLink)`

3) As an additional note it is a good idea to get into the habit of using

```
$valueToInputIntoSql = mysqli_real_escape_string($MysqliLink,$value);
```

to escape apostraphes and suchlike, although it's not quite perfect, it goes a long way to make inputs more safe.

4) 
I think that is about it, from my memory of doing this to about 12 different sites I inherited, search and replace site wide is a massive time saver, If anyone nudges my memory for other replaces to do I'll add them in here.

Good luck. And then read up on OO DB connections too.

Comment: If my solution works you can tick the tick beside my answer at the top, or the topic. and/or click the up arrow to add credit to my answer. Cheers.